# I can't find packages to annotate gpl20995 and 6244

Tags: r

which R annotation package can be useful to annotate GPL20995 and GPL6244?
I tried hgu133plus2.db but it didn't work!

Comment: Maybe GitHub package `" dongzhuoer/rGEO.data "`.

Comment: oh tnx . would you help me in order how to work with this package??? I'v never work with it